# Bigquery unnest and remove bag from nested array of struct column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How do I cast/convert/unnest/renest and move data from 2 columns (vendordatacosts and gdprconsentedpurposes) which look like this:
[image]

whose data types are :
vendordatacosts :

```
STRUCT<bag ARRAY<STRUCT<array_element STRUCT<vendorid INT64, tokens STRUCT<bag ARRAY<STRUCT<array_element STRUCT<token STRING, costcpm FLOAT64>>>>, costcpm FLOAT64, revenuecpm FLOAT64, feetype INT64>>>>
```

gdprconsentedpurposes :

```
STRUCT<bag ARRAY<STRUCT<array_element INT64>>>
```

into a simpler format like this without the *bag* :

[image]

whose datatypes are :
vendordatacosts :

```
ARRAY<STRUCT<vendorid INT64, tokens ARRAY<STRUCT<token STRING, costcpm FLOAT64>>, costcpm FLOAT64, revenuecpm FLOAT64, feetype INT64>>
```

gdprconsentedpurposes :

```
ARRAY<INT64>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a example with some fields:

```sql
SELECT 
  ARRAY(SELECT 
      STRUCT(
        b.array_element.vendorid as vendorid,
        ARRAY(SELECT
            STRUCT(
              t.array_element.token as token,
              t.array_element.costcpm
            )
          FROM UNNEST(b.array_element.tokens.bag) t
        ) as tokens
      ) 
    FROM UNNEST(vendordatacost.bag) b
  ) as vendordatacost
FROM sample
```

Output schema:

[image: schema]

Comment: great ! worked perfect - thanks.